# Using ASP NET Core Identity for Authenticating automation/service accounts

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, service-accounts

I have an ASP Net core API app with Identity Core for user and claim management and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication as an Authentication middle-ware. I am using JWT middleware to issue bearer tokens.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = issuerSigningKey,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                };
            });
```

This works fine for Username/Password scenarios. Now I want to use another API (Azure Logic App) to make some REST calls to the ASP Core API, which has protected endpoints.

I am looking for guidance on how to achieve this. I have a couple of ideas:

1. Create a user in the identity table which will act as a **service/automation account**, same as a normal human user. Advantage - no change required. Downside - sounds a bit hacky.
2. Create some sort of an **encrypted string/token**, save it in API app.settings, and ask the consumer APIs to pass it in the header. Advantage - Easy to implement, downside - not sure how it will work with JWT bearer authentication pipeline. Also, sounds kind of static and insecure.
3. Implement something like an **App ID and Secret**. Advantage - Seems like a good practice, is scale-able for multiple Apps (consumers). Downside - I have no idea how to implement it using ASP core Identity and that too along with JWT pipeline.

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Identity is not the same thing as the Authentication/Authorization middleware. Identity is specifically for managing users and associate claims. The auth middleware is entirely separate. Identity merely plugs into it, to allow the auth to happen against Identity's stores. To handle auth for an API, you simply need an endpoint that can create an auth token based on some input. Then, you'll need to plugin into the authorization middleware to validate said token. While you can do all this manually, you should really use something like IdentityServer, as it has all this built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ChrisPratt, corrected the wording of the question. I would like to use the existing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, so was hoping to find a mechanism to best handle User auth as well as services auth. I do have a token endpoint for User tokens.